# How to implement the division of two relations in mapreduce?

Tags: mapreduce, pseudocode, cartesian-product, relational-algebra

I want to implement the division of two relations in MapReduce. I have two relations: T(A,B,C) and U(B,C). I know that [image]

for the relations R(A,B,D) and S(A,B). This is pretty much my scenario. I am not sure how I would go about implementing this in mapReduce. With my limited knowledge Im guessing there would be 3 map reduce jobs. I would assume the first round might be the (projection of B -C(T) x U) - T

**Mapper 1** our input is either a tuple from T or U

If tuple *t* belongs to (a,b,c) from T then we have key: NULL and value ("T" a)

if tuple *t* belongs to (b,c) from U then we have key NULL and value (b,c "U")

With these values we can perform the cartesian product between ("T" a ) with the values (b,c "U") and emit the new key null and value (a,b,c)

Reducer 2
we remove from the new cartesian tuples any that are in the original table T and emit the tuples that are not contained in the original table.

I am confused about what I would do next. Whether it would be another mapper or could I use again a reducer for the next B -C projection? I'm not sure if I did the first round correctly. If anyone can tell me the steps how this would go preferably in pseudo-code that would me understand. Online I do not find any answers for this.

Comment: ] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: Please don't use A & B in both the definition & the example data. What is B-C? For T(a,b,c) & U(b,c) as R & S, the projections, all on A-B, are on {a}. Re "pretty much": That R/S is A tuples that appear in R with every tuple in S. There's no need to calculate those rows by executing particular subexpressions just because that is the structure of a particular definition. R/S is A subtuples whose B row set in R is a superset of S. You could pair each R partition with S. PS What exactly can the input be? Sorted or indexed? NULLs or duplicate rows?--If so how how does the definition treat them?